# Rewrite rules ignored

Tags: rewrite-rules

Why are my rewrite rules being ignored by WordPress?

I've got the following rule added:

```
news/([0-9]{4})/?$  archive-news.php?year=$matches[1]
```

but the URL `news/2015` gives a 404.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rewrite rules should point to `index.php`. This is a reference to the main `index.php` file through which all requests are routed, not a template file.